# Ajax запрос html страницы

Tags: html, ajax

Никак не могу разобраться с ajax. Вот скрипт. Имеется сайт с товарами. Нужно по кнопке "показать еще" добавить новых товаров. Как я понимаю, если я установлю локальный сервер на свой ПК, то смогу получать moreAps.html только со своего компа. 
Что делать, если мне нужно показать сайт на другом ПК с гитхаба. Где мне тогда хранить файл moreAps.html ?

Правильно ли оформлен запрос?
И могу ли я обойтись без PHP здесь?

```
$('.main-page__button').on('click', function(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'moreAps.html',
    cache: false,
    method: 'get',
    type: 'html',
    success: function(html){
        $('.appartments').html(html);
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

ajax делает запрос на указанный url, и когда придет ответ на этот запрос, то ответ обработается в callback-функции, которая указана в success.
На какой сервер уйдет твой запрос - это уже другой вопрос. Уйдет на тот, который ты указал в поле url.

Если ты указал moreAps.html, то да, только локально.

Если ты делаешь ajax-запрос, то этот запрос должен кто-то обработать и дать тебе ответ. Поэтому как вариант - тебе нужно установить apache, который будет принимать запрос, и возможно php, который будет обрабатывать запрос. И отдавать ответ обратно клиенту, где ответ обработается в коллбэк-функции.

А вообще советую почитать про архитектуру веб-приложений.

Comment: Ну про суть ajax я понял. Непонятно, где хранить файл. Меня просят показать как работает сайт на стороне. Показать с Гитхаба. На какой сервер ссылаться ajax? Куда непосредственно я могу залить файл?